# Integration inverse to derivation.

Tags: integration

(Proof that Integration is inverse to derivation)

I would like to ask if it's enough of a proof if I would say that if we have a mapping $A \to B$ that gives $x$ its derivative $x'$it is injective and is called "Differentiation".

If a mapping is injective it has an inverse mapping $B \to A$ it's also  injective and it gives $x'$ its initial form(don't know how to call it in english) and this mapping is called Integration.

Sorry for my english but is it a good enough proof or does it require deeper analytical proving?
And if so, could you give me a hint how to get such proof?

Comment: Proof of what, exactly?

Comment: Oh.. Well That Integration is inverse to Derivation. Sorry for not making it clear before.

Comment: I have edited. Please check  haven't unintentionally changed the meaning.

Comment: In answer to the question if I have understood correctly . $x^2 +1$ has the same derivative as $x^2$ with respect to $x $. Antiderivatives may differ by a constant and so the reverse mapping isn't one to one.

Comment: If you are referring to real functions you should to specify the type of integral (Riemann, Lebesgue, etc.) and the set of functions that you are dealing.

Comment: Karl. Oh of course. So this is the wrong way to go about it. Thank you I overlooked the constants.

Comment: I suspect you wish to look up the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Even if you show that differentiation has an inverse, you still have to show that this inverse is integration.

Comment: I think the source of your confusion is that the word “integrate” is also used for “compute the antiderivative” (with confusingly similar symbols: $\int$ for **indefinite integral** = antiderivative, and $\int_a^b$ for **definite integral**). This kind of “integration” is *by definition* the inverse operation of differentiation, so it needs no proof. The interesting thing is that the *definite* integral $\int_a^x$ provides an antiderivative (under suitable assumptions of course).